# How to convert a UNIX timestamp to date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to convert a UNIX timestamp into a YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS date for a Discord Bot, but to no Avail, is ther any way I could do this properly (Since I've been comparing results with a webpage)

Comment: [This _couldn't possibly_ be a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+unix+timestamp+to+date) It is also highly recommend to show "to no avail" attempts and errors / incorrect results.

Comment: I've tried [This Attemp](https://hastebin.com/ahamamuged.js) but it wasn't precise at all. other attemtp just gave me time, instead of a constructed Date

Comment: See also [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/215552)

Comment: "it wasn't precise at all" Do you mean "accurate" rather than "precise"? Because that code would be precise to the second; you could easily add `getMillisecond()` to add precision. Accuracy depends on what you're expecting, since UNIX timestamps (and JavaScript Dates) are derived from UTC (as the "How to format" link's answers discuss).

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a UNIX timestamp is as easy as just assigning a number to the `Date` constructor.

```js
let unix_timestamp = Date.now();
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp);
console.log(date);
```

<sub>`Date.now()` retrieves the current UNIX timestamp</sub>

On how to format a date, I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) will help.

Comment: Not really how to parse a unix timestamp, but how to format it into a readable time. (UNIX -> Time -> Formated Time)
1491673362160 Being the timestamp in my case

Comment: @Mateo That's unlikely to be a UNIX timestamp, since it produces a date in the year 49239. It's more likely to be a JavaScript timestamp, since that would produce a date in the year 2017. But I don't know the use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

```
moment.unix(value).calendar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer thanks those who contributed

```
var d = new Date(convertIDtoUnix(ID));
        timeStampCon = d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();
```